# In MySql, How to Associate Three Random Rows from One Table to Each Row of a Another Table

Tags: mysql, random

I have a table of Friends (Ann, Bob, Carl) and a table of Fruits (Apple, Banana, Cherry, Date, Fig, Grapefruit)

I need to create an intersection table (Friends X Fruit) that associates each Friend with 3 randomly selected fruits.

For example:
Ann might be associated with Cherry, Date, Fig
Bob might be associated with Apple, Fig, Banana
Carl might be associated with Banana, Cherry, Date

I have developed a script that works well for only ONE friend (pasted below), but I am struggling to expand the script to handle all of the friends at once.

**(If I remove the WHERE clause, then every friend gets assigned the same set of fruits, which doesn't meet my requirement)**.

Setup statements and current script pasted below.

Thank you for any guidance!

```
CREATE TABLE TempFriends ( FirstName VARCHAR(24) );
CREATE TABLE TempFruits ( FruitName VARCHAR(24) );
CREATE TABLE FriendsAndFruits( FirstName VARCHAR(24), FruitName VARCHAR(24) );
INSERT INTO TempFriends VALUES ('Ann'), ('Bob'), ('Carl');
INSERT INTO TempFruits VALUES ('Apple'), ('Banana'), ('Cherry'), ('Date'), ('Fig'), ('Grapefruit');

INSERT INTO FriendsAndFruits( FirstName, FruitName )
SELECT FirstName, FruitName
FROM TempFriends
INNER JOIN  ( SELECT FruitName FROM TempFruits ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3 ) RandomFruit
WHERE FirstName = 'Bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO FriendsAndFruits
SELECT FirstName, 
       FruitName
FROM (
  SELECT FirstName, 
         FruitName, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName ORDER BY RAND()) rn
  FROM TempFriends
  CROSS JOIN TempFruits
  ) subquery
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

```
INSERT INTO FriendsAndFruits( FirstName, FruitName )
SELECT FirstName, FruitName
FROM TempFriends
JOIN LATERAL ( 
  SELECT FruitName 
  FROM TempFruits 
  ORDER BY TempFriends.FirstName, RAND() LIMIT 3
  ) RandomFruit;
```

```
INSERT INTO FriendsAndFruits( FirstName, FruitName )
SELECT FirstName, FruitName
FROM TempFriends
JOIN LATERAL ( 
  SELECT TempFriends.FirstName tmp, FruitName 
  FROM TempFruits 
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
  ) RandomFruit;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H3O30rFe)

Comment: Thank you very much @Akina. Is one preferred vs. the others?

Comment: It depends. See plans, compare in practice.